# React Native - ListView renders only half of the data

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to React Native and trying to make an iOS app. The problem have bothered me for several days and I've checked the issue [[ListView] renders all rows? #499](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/499) and some questions on SO but still don't know what is wrong. (I've tried to add `flex: 1` in containers but still not work)

As you can see below, I log `this.state.dataSource` and there are 20 rows in data, as seen in `_cachedRowCount`, `_dataBlob`, `_dirtyRows`... but there'll be only 10 rows rendered, as I log `rowID` in `_renderRow()` method. But sometimes, there are 20 rows rendered...

[image]

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  this.fetchData(this.props.access_token);
},

fetchData: function(token) {

  var self = this;

  fetch('https://api.douban.com/shuo/v2/statuses/home_timeline', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
    }
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((d) => {

      self.setState({
        loaded: true,
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(d),
      });

    })
    .done();
},

_renderRow: function(post, sectionID, rowID) {
  console.log(rowID);

  return (
    <TouchableHighlight>
      <View style={styles.cell}>
       ...
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    );
},
```

Any help will be appreciate!

Comment: Can you post the code where you define the ListView?

Comment: I have not know what was wrong but it works fine now. So I will update the question if the problem re-appears.